# Add nested object to mapped type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this rather lengthy type defintion

```
export interface AddedAnimalsState {
    animals: {
        [P in AllAnimalsTypeKeys]: AnimalToRaceMap[P]
    }
}

export type AllAnimalsTypeKeys = keyof AnimalToRaceMap

export interface AnimalToRaceMap {
    dog: DogData
    cat: CatData,
}

export type DogData = {
    [P in DogsTypesKeys]: DogsTypesMap[P]
}

export type CatData = {
    [P in CatsTypesKeys]: CatsTypesMap[P]
}

export type DogsTypesKeys = keyof DogsTypesMap
export type CatsTypesKeys = keyof CatsTypesMap

export interface DogsTypesMap {
    poodle: PoodleData,
    sausageDog: SausageDogData
}

export interface CatsTypesMap {
    tiger: TigerData
}

export type PoodleData = AnimalsData<AddedDogState, PoodleSorting>
export type SausageDogData = AnimalsData<AddedSausageDogState, SausageDogSorting>
export type TigerData = AnimalsData<AddedTigerState, TigerSorting>

export interface AnimalsData<TItem extends AnimalsUiItem, TSorting extends AnimalsSorting> {
    items: TItem[]
    sorting: TSorting
    allSelected: boolean,
    view: TableOrListView
}

export interface AnimalsUiItem {
    ui: AdditionalUiAnimalInformation
}

export interface AnimalsSorting {
    name: SortOrder | null,
    height: SortOrder | null,
    selected: SortOrder | null,
    dateAdded: SortOrder | null,
}

export interface PoodleSorting extends AnimalsSorting {
    mother: SortOrder | null,
    color: SortOrder | null,
    age: SortOrder | null,
    poodleshness: SortOrder | null
}

export interface SausageDogSorting extends AnimalsSorting{
    length: SortOrder | null,
    sausageDogNess: SortOrder | null,
    father: SortOrder | null,
}

export interface TigerSorting extends AnimalsSorting{
    viciousness: SortOrder | null,
    origin: SortOrder | null,
}

export interface AdditionalUiAnimalInformation {
    selected: boolean
    dateAdded: Date,
    title: string,
}

export interface AdditionalAnimalKeys {
    id: number,
    travelOptionId: number,
}

export interface AddedDogState extends DogState, AdditionalAnimalKeys {
    ui: AdditionalUiAnimalInformation,
}

export interface AddedSausageDogState extends SausageDogState, AdditionalAnimalKeys {
    ui: AdditionalUiAnimalInformation,
}

export interface AddedTigerState extends TigerState, AdditionalAnimalKeys {
    ui: AdditionalUiAnimalInformation,
}

export enum TableOrListView {
    List, Table
}

export enum SortOrder {
    ASC = 'asc', DESC = 'desc'
}

export interface DogState {}

export interface SausageDogState {}

export interface TigerState {}
```

Which results in this object

```
const awesomeAnimals: AddedAnimalsState = {
    animals: {
        dog: {
            poodle: {
                items: [],
                sorting: {
                    name: null,
                    mother: null,
                    color: null,
                    age: null,
                    height: null,
                    dateAdded: null,
                    selected: null,
                    poodleshness: null,
                },
                allSelected: false,
                view: TableOrListView.Table
            },
            sausageDog: {
                items: [] as AddedSausageDogState[],
                sorting: {
                    name: null,
                    length: null,
                    sausageDogNess: null,
                    father: null,
                    height: null,
                    dateAdded: SortOrder.DESC,
                    selected: null,
                },
                allSelected: false,
                view: TableOrListView.Table
            },
        },
        cat: {
            tiger: {
                items: [] as AddedTigerState[],
                sorting: {
                    viciousness: null,
                    name: null,
                    origin: null,
                    dateAdded: SortOrder.DESC,
                    selected: null,
                    height: null                
                    },
                allSelected: false,
                view: TableOrListView.Table
            },
        }
    },
};
```

I am trying to change the resulting object to look like this

```
const awesomeAnimals: AddedAnimalsState = {
    animals: {
        dog: {
            poodle: {
                items: [],
            },
            sausageDog: {
                items: [] as AddedSausageDogState[],
            },
            ui: {
                sorting: {
                    mother: null,
                    father: null,
                    height: null,
                    name: null,
                    color: null,
                    dateAdded: SortOrder.DESC,
                    selected: null,            
                },
                allSelected: false,
                view: TableOrListView.Table
            }
        },
        cat: {
            tiger: {
                items: [] as AddedTigerState[],
            },
            ui: {
                sorting: {
                    viciousness: null,
                    origin: null,
                    height: null,
                    name: null,
                    color: null,
                    dateAdded: SortOrder.DESC,
                    selected: null,                   
                },
                allSelected: false,
                view: TableOrListView.Table
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Not that in `sorting` there are some common props (`height`, `name`, `color`, `dateAdded`, `selected`). I am not sure how to restructure my type definitions in order for it to work.

I though about adding it here

```
// common between DogSorting and CatSorting
export interface AnimalsSorting {
    name: SortOrder | null,
    height: SortOrder | null,
    color: SortOrder | null,
    selected: SortOrder | null,
    dateAdded: SortOrder | null,
}

// individual CartSorting
export interface CatSorting extends AnimalsSorting{
    viciousness: SortOrder | null,
    origin: SortOrder | null,
}

// individual DogSorting
export interface DogSorting extends AnimalsSorting{
    mother: SortOrder | null,
    father: SortOrder | null,
}


export interface AddedAnimalsState {
    animals: {
        [P in AllAnimalsTypeKeys]: AnimalToRaceMap[P]
        ui: {
            sorting: {
                ...CatSorting or ...DogSorting, depending on P in AllAnimalsTypeKeys
            },
            allSelected: false, // common
            view: TableOrListView.Table // common
        }
    }
}
```

but I am no sure how. Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQQBNDhD8kEBbTAGwGcBlGTVOAbwFgAoOXuTCtXoAudtz4S4AbQAKiJARo1yVWnQAqATzDAA0sE10AuqJVD1EAEo5gAWUxhZR8XwC%203d126hIsODG08fCUzNS0dfUM4AF44AGsDCHQCQVoLa1x7MG5vcGh4ZFQMGxTVGnSbLLEePkIIAHNRABEGppZMF15sFlEAYRY25gAaDxyuH3z-QLgW%20sHMGOqJWXkZho1AukjjZvXw4Dosp1Gvcby-AJ04fph5xc4a3hXka5YNnS2DHdeYd4OjmTOLieMYTC7TWZ-T5RWIJTRJNb1KFZXK%20eCXPA3KHbRZwhFY-aHByg84FFBoLC4RHIhxLPiQCCEGjAUQyCCM5nzEaPOB0TAAVz59WAs1EDAFQpFrXaJ1Rk0KFJKBM2VQeEhgCGFUFE6k1aHmsrOaKmVzZHJF7UWoXo8wAPEQSIRZkwWMAhnAzUzgAx8sh6gA%20OXgq7iwWYYWzO6xa10O0O0ihyXO5iod2J8NS%20o%202B%20wNGyYYuC6rVR0pCWPte3EUjFtAu1NFvVQbMapABknGhXFKkxu3qACSqEocFAqCQhDoZbUAFUEIPgJR3eoW36RyAxxOp-QV23-XTeAgh3QdfPKFIgRI6L62zqd-VOvwlAxgMzsKhCKIAEbs5kCbkSAA3BBgAAdx1TBP2ZAB5KAABkEDoGAADVgJAw0wTJIpKSCVJ6FnU99zgfkEFMYhDwQCAkFoWdrX7JB0GgagNUo9DSXkLCShjO9CKoygWTgFsYJIKA4AAHzgJB%20SUf8%20AAC2ATVZJgMV8iEtAxIkqSaBk3g6BfYA31IFTYDUkTxMk6SH0IV14w-ATVKgYSNIs7TWM7cluzwT1mW40dgHHScuOvepCMoCAYHk7V7JMxz1PMrSdLgbAIBoaBjJgUznISh8M3SzL4ssnkGS9OhZKQA5j2ijLYrMzSlDc%20UPOwgSJQzZ1grXDdAtwxhgrVPhmTbCK8pqrLCsvVqIwaAA5CqRqcgrXJ5LAIrQea4rqpaQXzPwu2a2tmw6vyAq3XqczbfreCA7AKMFcq6EqwTRsWxLoE1ZB1tqlzuW2jD2MVHsyOYqiaBo3C6IYqAmIohRLt5fTDLs78UuAAQrJs6s7MGN0Hw1GBmVERCoD9H6O0ajjAcIcjKNoa0cThhA7MkyhPzQRKYCgTAAJfKCwGB-smf5Fm2Ya3ams4zHk1dTr-M3KWGwdamQbpr5COI0iqeB6iEFo%20jGJYGHSdOP69olx10ymrMUzwY7NwtzN6zdAggZh2ncPph91edzXXdBnXwb1qGDcoo2g0wgGgkxg7HZlk7o%20t91Fa15R3dVuGvaT32wbKCH9eB0OdvgfyhaLCDoLghDkNQwj4MQpcy%20AUWi%20ZqrMrh-AGF6RYAHJMDobBu-dJoAFFO57kh%20%207pv-s8xEY7YX62NNql7flvAF7JsWKbwePpY305uGSpBEPkcjaEdjXSC4637hynrRDhiQ6kaQjJHpdkvQfh837fw8F0q88iUf6SCvOdF%20j9gE-14vxb639IFvzCqtKKsCeTwLfslVKyDsqoLQRIXKm0gG4LkgpeoSlRAoKIT-ayqBbLkOwZQt%20elXzvjoeNBhEhirMlKvdSqFCGGuEIfA2gNBnzMKMnALA9AcY4PgUBUC4FILABgrXKuoEAB06gG5wLfgI7RIDJqZi-jIyBf9KAAKMPwQKmNV4NEdoAvRwDQGtnAQ4tB0DWFLXYRIQa9RhoENcfAvkYZLazQeh4wRRCVqRXCQEyB8lFLKX8cY3B1DgC0NbjVNRI9O4RNwUwgyLCknsN0ckn%20wjREFPEZIvSuSf5yLAqXRRyjK4oXUZoxRsSSnAK6T-boiSIFvw1FqIx7DTHmMsd7GsTY7FGFqYw4KIyvFXQQDdCAd05pFKWRJTAfEYmlPgW9eoH1NlLNSekp6wksmj16HMyB%20TEZ7K2XAeJpDEkuXYbE7pty8FPgRoU6p0j2H1IUeXFRrSQIaK0fsuAPSdEPhKa4AA3EAA)

Comment: It's unclear what keys are and aren't present in `sorting`. For example, `mother` from `PoodleSorting` is present, but `poodleshness` from the same interface is absent.

Comment: @Thomas I am not sure if I understand you correct. In the new sorting definition there are common keys (`height`, `name`, `color`, `dateAdded`, `selected`) and individual keys: `viciousness` and `origin` for `tiger`, `mother` and `father` for `dog`. I do not need the "old" sorting (where each animal like `poodle`, `sausageDog` and `tiger` have their "individual" sorting) anymore. I edited the Q to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt comes quite close.

The individual races don't have UI attributes anymore, so they are simplified down to:

```
export type PoodleData = AnimalsData<AddedDogState>
export type SausageDogData = AnimalsData<AddedSausageDogState>
export type TigerData = AnimalsData<AddedTigerState>

export interface AnimalsData<TItem extends AnimalsUiItem> {
    items: TItem[]
}
```

On the other hand, the containers `DogData` and `CatData` get an additional attribute, `ui`. Because these are mapped types, you can't add any other attributes to them directly, i.e. this is rejected:

```
export type DogData = {
    [P in DogsTypesKeys]: DogsTypesMap[P]
    ui: AdditionalUiAnimalInformation     // ERROR: A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.(7061)
}
```

What you *can* do, however, is require that each container implements two interfaces: the one containing a key for each race, and the other containing the `ui` key:

```
export interface AddedAnimalsState {
    animals: {
        [P in AllAnimalsTypeKeys]: AnimalToRaceMap[P] & {
            ui: {
                sorting: AnimalToSortingMap[P],
                allSelected: boolean,
                view: TableOrListView.Table
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get that to work, you only need an additional interface that ties the animal type to its sorting type:

```
export interface AnimalToSortingMap {
    dog: DogSorting,
    cat: CatSorting,
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQQBNDhD8kEBbTAGwGcBlGTVOAbwFgAoOXuTCtXoAudtz4S4AbQAKiJARo1yVWnQAqATzDAA0sE10AuqJVD1EAEo5gAWUxhZRuADIxPSZ4CuCUZw+egXB00DDIAOamgrQWDKER9o4yRgA04kGBtDQMwDTA2KiEogBGEBB5AmkBGRIAbgjAAO6i6pjFeQDyUAAyCHQwAGoNjQB0re3A6TUAvlOSs9ULC9ygkLBwMNp4+Epmalo6+oZwALxwANYGEOgE0TQW1riJ3CvgofKoGDa3qvdWNol3BJCBBInAACKg8EsTBzbAsUQAYRY0OYVWWXFW72QnywuB+5ggcVgCQcQL4ILBkPCxLCSHCVQk8JgSJYtIi6JemLe602OghUJhp3JvFk8gF4Q0WzoR2MompUp0dESTm4GKxvK2cGRMFRmGF-gkYuQ2pYiuAMoMctNMHNyocqq4GNea3gfLwCoOFtlwsummuErtz25ro2Wp1dp9Zz9AYjXvtYC5GvgOLQeI9oKDZMNfEgEEIeVEMjKBeAesZfDomC8VfCZdBogY1dr9fCerVSZ5KZQae+celgJzvDCdagLQQo-bTs7ofdcGL+byeuFe3oeoAPEQSIRqUwWMAAHwu95zps1zB16nLs6rugbrekM8t3fMVBHkMnrXqCdoa8EtT3sQpDfqOe5vjO2I9l8+K3hu6gAJKoJQcCgKgSCEHQ-70AAqggiHAJQB4iogSF0C0+GUFIRgdlwx7rKm0HbHcdC4RRxE+KYxAIGEEBILQuGrvBSDoNA1A8UgNF0d2uLfLe7L0sRfGUMAjahF0JBQHAAA+cBIF4SgVrwAAWwATkZLJwLS6loNpun6TQhlwNg5TQKpsDWZpOl6QZcx0Lk+SFG5MAebZ3kOXMhD7g+RSWWpUAaaF9mcrRH70VB6Y2vJ4QoSAaEYVhjDxPSQ5wPU2AIBANZIBaZGxe58U2V5SVzNAE7IEFIVNT504pcmHy9viu5FdlqHAOhmFycNJWUBAMAmWOdXBQ1nl2d1EhYHNaAdctiXdeqXb9YxBBceJ-EIIJwmiSwFUKCVfl5AUpAlGUFQSdUkWoNF8r7o5YQwIWwQwFAHKSal0kDdsJ03bQq4+iVCAxXplDFGgv1QJgtS5B0YDifBiNeMjqOg31DEZdFL77jleWYRTqApMdhDcdDyh3HDcwcQzTO8WdF0iVAYk3clUmHWTQGEE+F6tmBeCjeNlnNpLtPAPTW5c3xLO-Gz1Qc6rp00AJdxCXzAu8ULYMi7JYsgWg0tU2N+XW1A0sq1D3Ma0IWsSDrrvqwbvxG1d4lm31Y0E3A4ydD0fSDMMxG9P09MR5MPXC6HyFWTtJX4AwiLCgA5JgdDYHn9PggAojn+ckEXefEwdpPfEr7D7aGDf4hLl6grbbAt5BMn4o73cYs5SD9PwjQWhAym3px25ya+eBnCVAi-LVJXAg2xFBHmpZ+HMNS8NxBG1VRjlBNMZ+BFW56d2C68H0flAn84hcM4+Cu39Lp-74EF8-94vgt4HxCCSeke9qgH0kDNTaC0wqX0gbwDa81RBwP-ggkyZkLKoIgQg3gSkVKrXCjg3BzkaCuUIfAhBH1gBfUWh5EY5cc6UMgfdAKT0KGQLQefZhmQlA5AeoFOAWB6DKy4YEeoTQWhtEjvHGOTQxjSOTpAhY3C0HMnAZAkcW0gE1Efs-fgE0rY-idgvb+xD5g8N4Bze+NQQF0jvmImoZUKpVRqig5q5jIGtXCO1ChjiMgYPCOZdxa1cGSHwSEohYTJCkPIdg6JwIopi22hpBhFdESWIyKwx6+MDIJN4P4iQf9PG8OyP5HJohhF+UyXUYYUiJhdFkUMeRSd-EqN-nMYp0wADcQA)

Comment: Aaaah, its the `&` I was missing... I kept on asking myself how to get the additional `ui: {....}` in there. Thanks!

Comment: I do have a follow up Question. Is there a way to make an individual interface out of this: `AnimalToRaceMap[P] & {ui: { sorting: AnimalToSortingMap[P], allSelected: boolean, view: TableOrListView.Table }}`? I need it for some other functions.

Comment: Something like `type Whatever<P in AllAnimalsTypeKeys> = AnimalToRaceMap[P] & {ui: { sorting: AnimalToSortingMap[P], allSelected: boolean, view: TableOrListView.Table }}`?

Comment: Something that I can pass as a type-definition to a function, so that the compiler knows in the variable is this `{items: AnimalToRaceMap[P] & {ui: {sorting: AnimalToSortingMap[P], allSelected: boolean, view: TableOrListView.Table}}`

Comment: Your suggestion gives me this compiler error `Variance annotations are only supported in type aliases for object, function, constructor, and mapped types.`

Comment: Sorry, should be `type Whatever<P extends AllAnimalsTypeKeys>` of course.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Could you also have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76563146/flatten-data-structure-in-typescript
It is sort of a follow up on this one.